# Display date from database using jquery fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I'm using the jquery fullcalendar plugin.  I can display dynamic dates on a button click.  The issue I have now is when loading the dates from the db all the dates populate just one day.

Here is the code with the call to the web service:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev, next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month, agendaWeek, agendaDay'
    },
    defaultView: 'month',
    editable: true,
    allDaySlot: false,
    selectable: true,
    slotMinutes: 15,    
    events: 'DAL/WebService1.asmx/GetEvents',
    allDay:false
});
```

Here is the date from that web method
[image]

Comment: dont you need your events to be in a certain type of format from the database? I thought you at least needed these columns `start`, `end`, `title`. Look at the documentation for the **Required** fields: http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Object/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out how to get the calendar to render dates separately with this code here.  Hopefully helps somebody in the future

```
                var events = [];
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                events: function (start, end, timezone,callback) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'DAL/WebService1.asmx/GetEvents',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function (data) {
                            console.log(data);
                            var events = [];
                            $(data).each(function (index, d) {
                                events.push({
                                    title: d.title,
                                    start: d.startDate
                                });
                            });
                            callback(events);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#calendar').fullcalendar('renderEvent',event_object,'stick')
```

This will attach your event to its date on the calendar.  The event_object only needs a title and a start date to be valid, but I'd suggest adding an id to make editing/deleting easier.

[Render event documentation](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/renderEvent/)

Comment: nope that had same results.  All the events posted to the same day in the calendar.